# SSD as a primary hard drive with OS on it opens secondary HDD very slowly

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd

Today I bought a Sandisk 240GB SSD. I put it in my PC and then installed Windows 7. I have another HDD (WDC WD10EZEX) that was my primary hard drive, and it had three partitions. I made the Sandisk bootable first and formatted from the Windows 7 installation (what used to be C:).

The Windows installation and the SSD are working fine, however if I try to open the partitions from the other hard drive everything either crashes or opens after 10 to 15 minutes. I checked both partitions from the HDD, no errors were found (or at least nothing popped after completing the process).

I downloaded the Data Lifeguard Diagnostics program and this is what I get:

[image: Data LifeGuard Diagnostics]

I have also tried turning off the Search indices in order to make reading the HDD faster, but that didn't help.  What might be causing that slow opening of folders and files and windows explorer crashes?

Comment: Were all three partitions assigned drive letters? Have you tried using the Disk Management snap-in for Computer Management? Perhaps manually change the drive letters on the HDD partition(s) to ones furhter down the alphabet: I have seen drive letter conflicts with USB stick etc cause similar behavior.

Comment: Have you tried with any linux live distro? if the problem is reproducible, then it may be a hardware issue, maybe the disk controller or the motherboard, if not, then its some typical windows magic.

Comment: in the power settings of windows, disable the power saving for drives, maybe the drive is slow t resume from a sleep.